# Impact of converting from string to int in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hey I am sorting the list in kotlin. Using **sortBy** and **thenBy**. I was wondering is there impact on performance,speed,memory etc.  when we converting from string to int when sorting.

**Xyz.kt**

```
data class Xyz(
    val dataOne: String? = null,
    val dataTwo: String? = null,
    val dataThree: String? = null
)
```

**Third.kt**

```
fun main() {
    val list =getSortedListData()
    list.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}

private fun getUnSortedDataListData(): List<Xyz> {
    return listOf(
        Xyz("2", "3", "4"),
        Xyz("1", "5", "4"),
        Xyz("-1", "6", "4"),
        Xyz("-5", "-2", "4"),
        Xyz("-10", "-1", "4")
    )
}
```

Is there impact on when we converting from string to int in these function?

```
private fun getSortedListData(): List<Xyz> {
    val getUnSortedDataList = getUnSortedDataListData()
    return getUnSortedDataList.sortedWith(
        compareBy<Xyz> {   // or compareByDescending
            it.dataOne?.toInt() ?: 0   // or java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE
        }.thenBy {                    // or thenByDescending
            it.dataTwo?.toInt() ?: 0   // or java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE
        }
    )
}
```

Is there any probelem in above code? Can we do better for sorting in above code?

**vs**

I am thinking before sorting them, I'll convert to int and then sort. Is this better than above approach?

```
data class Xyz(
    val dataOne: String? = null,
    val dataTwo: String? = null,
    val dataThree: String? = null
) {
    val dataOneInInt = dataOne?.toInt()
    val dataTwoInInt = dataTwo?.toInt()
}


private fun getSortedListData(): List<Xyz> {
    val getUnSortedDataList = getUnSortedDataListData()
    return getUnSortedDataList.sortedWith(
        compareBy<Xyz> {   // or compareByDescending
            it.dataOneInInt ?: 0   // or java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE
        }.thenBy {                    // or thenByDescending
            it.dataTwoInInt ?: 0   // or java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Converting to Int does have some performance impact, so your optimization will help if you're doing a lot of them. But why store integer data as Strings in the first place if they always represent integers?

Comment: @Tenfour04 `getUnSortedDataListData()` list is coming from server. I just show mock up data.

Comment: @Tenfour04 which one you prefer when sorting then convert from string to int or before sorting ?

Comment: If the data is always Ints, I would convert the values to Ints when retrieved from the server and make the data class use Int properties. But if the data is sometimes Strings, then I'd use your optimization if sorting dozens or hundreds or more items.